# How can I check the error kind from Warp's try_bind_with_graceful_shutdown?

Tags: rust, error-handling, rust-warp

How can I check if the error from [`try_bind_with_graceful_shutdown`](https://docs.rs/warp/0.3.1/warp/struct.Server.html#method.try_bind_with_graceful_shutdown) is `std::io::ErrorKind::AddrInUse`?

Comment: It is a warp::Error not an `std::io::Error`, I dont think you can do it straight away.

Comment: With the way it's currently implemented (https://docs.rs/warp/0.3.1/src/warp/error.rs.html), it doesn't look like there are any great options, the options I can come up with are the compare the `Debug` and/or `Display` output strings, or to use `unsafe` code to get `inner` and *hope* it works (since there's no `#[repr(transparent)]` or `#[repr(C)]`) to extract the inner value, then use `downcast_ref` (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html#method.downcast_ref-2). I'd recommend finding a different way of solving this or filing an issue at https://github.com/seanmonstar/warp/issues.

Comment: Resists the temptation and the comments suggesting to parse the output of `Display` or `Debug`, and instead re-implement [what `warp` does itself](https://docs.rs/warp/0.3.1/src/warp/server.rs.html#296-310) in `try_bind...`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `warp` from the repository (instead of from crates.io), you can combine [`Error::source()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html#method.source) with [`Error::downcast_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html#method.downcast_ref-2) to do what you want:

```rust
let hello = warp::path!("hello" / String)
    .map(|name| format!("Hello, {}!", name));

match warp::serve(hello).try_bind_with_graceful_shutdown(SocketAddrV4::new(Ipv4Addr::new(0, 0, 0, 0), 8081), std::future::pending()) {
    Ok((_, future)) => future.await,
    Err(error) => {
        use std::error::Error;
        let mut current_error: &dyn Error = &error;
        let is_because_of_addr_in_use = loop {
            // get source of the error...
            current_error = match current_error.source() {
                // if there is one, continue
                Some(source) => source,
                // else, this error is not because of AddrInUse
                None => break false
            };
            //if the source is of type `std::io::Error`
            if let Some(io_error) = current_error.downcast_ref::<std::io::Error>() {
                break io_error.kind() == std::io::ErrorKind::AddrInUse;
            }
        };
            
        println!("Failed. is_because_of_addr_in_use == {}", is_because_of_addr_in_use);
    }
};
```

This prints `Failed. is_because_of_addr_in_use == true` if and only if `warp` failed to bind to the `SocketAddr` because it is already in use.

Note that this does **not** work for released versions of `warp` because [the pull request implementing `Error::source` for `warp::Error`](https://github.com/seanmonstar/warp/pull/825) is not yet released. If you are using a released version of `warp`, your best bet for now is probably to parse the output generated by the `Debug` or the `Display` implementation of `warp::Error`.